# Why Steenrod square $sq^1$ is zero

Tags: algebraic-topology

I would like to know why the Steenrod squares $sq^1$ is zero if $H^1(X, \Bbb Z_2)=0$ for a topological space $X$?  Here $\Bbb Z_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$?

My guess is this might follow from the fact that $sq^1$ is the Bockstein homomorphism, but I am unable to prove it.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in the comments. We have that $H^*(A_4;\Bbb F_2) = H^*(\Bbb Z_2^2;\Bbb F_2)^{\Bbb Z/3}$, that is, the fixed points. Now observe that the action of $\Bbb Z/3$ is to cyclically permute the nonzero elements of $\Bbb Z_2^2$, and also observe that $$H^*(\Bbb Z_2^2;\Bbb F_2) = \Bbb F_2[x,y],$$ where $|x|=|y|=1$. Now the action of the generator of $\Bbb Z/3$ pulls back $y$ to $x$ and $x$ to $x+y$. For a polynomial $p(x,y)$ to be invariant under this action, we just have $p(x+y,x) = p(x,y)$. It is a theorem of Noether that because $\Bbb Z/3$ has cardinality 3, which is invertible in $\Bbb F_2$, the invariant ring may be generated by polynomials of degree at most 3. By inspection we see there are no nonzero invariant degree 1 polynomials.

In degree 2 we have one nonzero invariant polynomial, $u_2 = x^2+xy+y^2$.
In degree 3 we find that the space  of invariant polynomials is spanned by $u_3 = x^3 + xy^2+y^3$ and $w_3 = x^2y + xy^2$.

It may be further checked that the only relation in this ring is $u_2^3=u_3^2 + u_3w_3.$ this doesn't matter for the solution of your problem though.

What remains is the fact that the Bockstein has $\beta(x) = x^2$ and $\beta(y) = y^2$, and it has the Leibniz rule $\beta(ab) = \beta(a)b + a\beta(b).$ Thus we have $\beta(x^2) = \beta(y^2)=0$, while $\beta(xy) = x^2y + xy^2$. That is, $\beta(u_2)=w_3$.

One also has $\beta(x^3) = x^4, \beta(y^3) = y^4$, while $\beta(x^2y) = \beta(xy^2) = x^2y^2$. This one finds $\beta(w_3) = 0$, but $\beta(u_3) = u_2^2$.

So I think your calculation of the Bockstein is wrong.

Comment: The bockstein is the same thing as $sq^1$

Comment: I understand my fault. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Could you please tell me why the action of $sq^1$ on $H^*(A_4;\Bbb Z_2)$ is coming from $H^*(\Bbb Z_2^2;\Bbb Z_2)$? I could not understand because $x,y$ does not belong to  $H^*(A_4;\Bbb Z_2)$, then still how can I say $\beta(x)=x^2$ here?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't true $sq^1=0$ even for a simply connected space. Consider any space $X$ with an element in first cohomology that squares nontrivially. Then $SX$ has an element in second cohomology that $sq^1$ acts on nontrivially. This is because $sq^1$ commutes with the suspension isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My statement was wrong. In case $H^*(X,\Bbb Z_2)\subseteq H^*(\Bbb Z_2^2, \Bbb Z_2)\cong \Bbb Z_2[x,y]$ then is my statement true? Here $\deg x=\deg y=1$.

Comment: Could you give some examples of spaces with cohomology like that, that aren’t wedge sums?

Comment: For example, consider $H^*(A_4; \Bbb Z_2)$. This is contained in $H^*(\Bbb Z_2^2;\Bbb Z_2)$. I want to show $sq^1$ in $H^*(A_4; \Bbb Z_2)$ is zero. $A_4$ is the alternating group of order $12$.

Comment: I couldn’t comment on that unless I knew how you figured out the cohomology had such a form.

Comment: I was wrong. The reason $sq^1=0$ was something else. Now I have found the exact reason. Thanks!